# How to get the TimeStamp in milliseconds which TimeZone is EDT

Tags: c, timestamp, loadrunner, epoch, timestamp-with-timezone

I have encountered a problem where the Timestamp captured in the script is in `EDT` timezone where as the functions like `web_save_timestamp_param` and `time_t` captures timestamp in UTC/GMT. Any Solution or function that can be used to resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GMT is +5 hours to EDT.  So, from your UTC/GMT number subtract (5*3600*1000) milliseconds, which represents five hours.  Example uses time seconds instead of milliseconds, but this should get you on the right path.

```
Action()
{
    long int seconds;


    seconds=time(NULL);
    lr_message(
        "UTC time:%ld\r\nEDT time:%ld",
        seconds,
        seconds-(3600*5));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: time(NULL) will return 10 digit timeStamp. In my case i need to get the 13 digit time Stamp in EDT format.

Comment: OK, grab the string from web_save_timestamp_param(), Convert it to a numeric datatype, run your math and voila!  You have your converted number